# check username of authenticated user then pass the username into javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, authentication, asp-classic

I have an ASP script that checks the username of the authenticated user, now I want to pass the username of the authenticated user into a javascript variable/string

ASP:

```
<%
Function isAuthorized()

Dim ipos
Dim ustring
Dim uname
Dim ilngth

ustring = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
ipos = Instr(ustring, "\") + 1
ilngth = Len(ustring) + 1
uname = Trim(Mid(ustring, ipos, ilngth - ipos))

End Function
%>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var chk = <%uname%>;
alert(chk);             
</script>
```

How can I make this work correctly and where in my code exactly do these elements go?

Answer (score 0):

Set a property to get the username: eg in c#
    Public string Username{ get { return Page.User.Identity.Name;} }

Call this in JavaScript using <%=Username%>

Comment: I ended up passing it into a hidden form element then extracting it with jquery .attr() (which I didn't want to do); I tried your method but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
var chk = "<%= uname %>";
alert(chk);             
</script>
```